# Connecting oracle 11g with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, oracle11g, xampp

I am trying to connect oracle 11g with codeigniter(V-2.1.4) using xampp(v-1.7.3) . I have changed my config.php to this :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;       
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'system';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'orcl';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and also changed `var $dbdriver = 'oci8';`  in DB_driver.php file. 
But um not able to connect with db. I am getting some sort of database error . It says :

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.    
Filename: G:\F\installed\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php    
Line Number: 124
```

I am giving line 118 - 127 of DB_driver.php here :

```
if ( ! $this->conn_id)
{
  log_message('error', 'Unable to connect to the database');

  if ($this->db_debug)
  {
    $this->display_error('db_unable_to_connect'); (this is line 124)
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

I want to add that when i try to connect with the following code i am able to see  "Succesfully connected with Oracle DB :-)" this message.

```
conn=oci_connect("system","root","localhost/orcl");
If (!$conn)
  echo "Failed to connect to Oracle";
else
  echo "Succesfully connected with Oracle DB :-)";
```

Answer (score 1):

make your database file config as below
host will be IP whre the oracle is installed..

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx.xxx.xx.xx)(PORT = 1521))
            (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XYZ)))';
$db['default']['username'] = "USERNAME";
$db['default']['password'] = "PASSWORD";
$db['default']['database'] = "DATABASE";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "oci8";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this configuration :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost/orcl'; // orcl is instance name
$db['default']['username'] = 'system';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
```

and

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;  // default TRUE
```

this work for me..